# Nested Try/Catch, Async/Await calls

Tags: javascript, http, asynchronous, axios, try-catch

I'm trying to await an axios post request within a asynchronous catch block. Nothing is being returned from the post request. Is it because I can't use await within a catch block?
Code looks something like:

```js
async function saveData() {
  console.log("Saving data");
}

async function doStuff(){
  try{
    const result = await Axios.get('http://localhost/blah');
    return result;
  } catch(err) {
    if(err.response.status === 400) {
      const otherResult = await Axios.post('http://localhost/postaddress');
      await saveData();
    }
  }
}
```

I've googled around for await within catch block and could only find stuff for C# updating their version to support this. Does Javascript support/not support this? If so why am I not getting anything back from the post request. Thanks!

Comment: Its ```axios``` not ```Axios```.

Comment: await should work fine in catch. Guessing something else is wrong, are you looking at the right status code when testing?

Comment: yurRa is correct. In addition, you can use await inside your catch block, but then you should place that inside another try/catch. But then you've simply recreated the pyramid of doom with your try/catch blocks. Consider calling another function from within the catch block that would submit the alternate request and handle it's own try/catch. This would better follow what is called the Single Responsibility principle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not using (for return) the variable `otherResult` that you defined as the result of the axios POST.

Have you tried doing:

```js
async function doStuff(){
  try{
    const result = await Axios.get('http://localhost/blah');
    return result;
  } catch(err) {
    if(err.response.status === 400) {
      const otherResult = await Axios.post('http://localhost/postaddress');
      await saveData();

      return otherResult; // <--- This line
      // return otherResult.response; // If you need the POST response
      // return otherResult.data; // If you need the POST response data
    }
  }
}
```

You should normally be able to use async/await inside a catch, just like everywhere else.